# How to sucessfully install redis-server, "tclsh8.5 not found" error

Tags: software-installation

How to successfully install redis-server on Ubuntu 11.04 .. I'm getting some Error! I wanted to install the current stable redis on Ubuntu 11.04

I see that in apt-repository the latest they have is

```
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Chris Lamb <lamby@debian.org> Architecture: i386   
Source: redis Version: 2:2.0.1-2 Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7), adduser
Filename: pool/universe/r/redis/redis-server_2.0.1-2_i386.deb
```

### uname -a

```
 2.6.38-11-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 29 19:05:14 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386      GNU/Linux
```

---

Install Procedure

```
$ wget http://redis.googlecode.com/files/redis-2.2.12.tar.gz
$ tar xzf redis-2.2.12.tar.gz
$ cd redis-2.2.12
$ make
```

### Error

```
cd src && make test
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/<username>/redis-2.2.12/src'
(cd ..; tclsh8.5 tests/test_helper.tcl --tags "" --file "")
/bin/sh: tclsh8.5: not found
make[1]: *** [test] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/<usernam>/redis-2.2.12/src'
make: *** [test] Error 2
```

Comment: is there a ".configure" file?  usually you have to run it i.e. "./configure" - as to the error - have you installed build-essential. have you got "tcl" installed?

Comment: There is no ".configure" file, but I just now checked that it didn't had tcl 8.5., which I have Installed now... Also Build-essential is already installed.  

Now testing .. 
make test && make install

Comment: I beat you by 2 minutes ;) If it is working please either upvote/accept my answer or add in your own answer and upvote/accept it.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

It is a common error that shows up when you did not install tcl8.5 ([source](http://groups.google.com/group/redis-db/browse_thread/thread/0d7ee0a350fd7b5e?pli=1)).

You need to install [tcl8.5](http://packages.ubuntu.com/tcl8.5)

```
sudo apt-get install -y tcl
```

Comment: Installation went successfully.
Here are the results.

...........................PIPELINING stresser (also a regression for the old ep.........................
831 tests, 831 passed, 0 failed

Comment: Excellent! tar install always is a little more tricky than deb installs :)

Comment: that's true indeed, sometimes we need to keep watch of the dependencies.

Answer (score 21):

1. **You have to install tcl**

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install tcl8.5
   ```
2. After the installation make test

   ```
   $ make test
   ```